# How can I extract chains of customers from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, series

I have a pandas dataframe with information about the deliveries done by a delivery person. In this pandas dataframe there are four columns. The first one is `DateTime`, the second one is `SortieNumber`, the third one is `CustomerName` and the fourth one is `ProductCode`.

I want to study this pandas dataframe and find chains within it. I want to find out if this delivery person delivers to the same customers in the same order in each sortie. I don’t care about the ordered products.
The first rows of the data frame are something like this:

```
DateTime            SortieNumber    CustomerName    ProductCode
01/01/2023 09:00:00  1              Josh            001
01/01/2023 09:10:00  1              Alice           002
01/01/2023 09:15:00  1              Robert          002
01/01/2023 12:00:00  2              Anna            001
01/01/2023 12:00:10  2              Anna            003
01/01/2023 12:15:00  2              Robert          003
01/01/2023 15:00:00  3              Josh            004
01/01/2023 15:05:10  3              Alice           003
01/01/2023 15:15:00  3              Robert          001
01/01/2023 15:30:10  3              Robert          002
01/01/2023 15:35:15  3              Robert          003
```

From this data, I want to say that the chain `Josh-Alice-Robert` happens in 2 of the 3 sorties, `Anna-Robert` happens in one of the three sorties and so on for the remaining rows.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ensure the rows are sorted by `SortieNumber` and `DateTime`, then remove the identical successive `SortieNumber`/`CustomerName`, [`groupby.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) as string and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
(df.sort_values(by=['SortieNumber', 'DateTime'])
   .loc[lambda d: d[['SortieNumber', 'CustomerName']]
                 .ne(d[['SortieNumber', 'CustomerName']].shift())
                 .any(axis=1)]
   .groupby('SortieNumber')['CustomerName'].agg('-'.join)
   .value_counts()
)
```

*NB. if you are sure that within one `SortieNumber` the same customer is never delivered with another customer in between, you can simplify the `.loc[…]` into `.drop_duplicates(['SortieNumber', 'CustomerName'])`.*

Output:

```
CustomerName
Josh-Alice-Robert    2
Anna-Robert          1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

If you want a proportion, pass `normalize=True` to `value_counts`:

```
CustomerName
Josh-Alice-Robert    0.666667
Anna-Robert          0.333333
Name: proportion, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The code is great. However, I have a question, if `Robert-Alice` appears twice and `Robert-Alice-Josh` appears once, the `Robert-Alice` of `Robert-Alice-Josh` isn't accounted in `Robert-Alice`. Can this be done as well?

Comment: @slow_learner yes, this could be done, but it will greatly increase the complexity of the code. You'll have to find the substrings/subsets

Comment: Thanks. I will try to work with your solution then

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime(['01/01/2023 09:00:00', '01/01/2023 09:10:00', '01/01/2023 09:15:00',
                               '01/01/2023 12:00:00', '01/01/2023 12:00:10', '01/01/2023 12:15:00',
                               '01/01/2023 15:00:00', '01/01/2023 15:05:10', '01/01/2023 15:15:00',
                               '01/01/2023 15:30:10', '01/01/2023 15:35:15']),
    'SortieNumber': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'CustomerName': ['Josh', 'Alice', 'Robert', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Robert', 'Josh', 'Alice', 
                     'Robert', 'Robert', 'Robert'],
    'ProductCode': ['001', '002', '002', '001', '003', '003', '004', '003', '001', '002', '003']
})

aa = df.groupby('SortieNumber')['CustomerName'].agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x.drop_duplicates()))

# Count occurrences 
chain_counts = aa.value_counts()
"""
CustomerName
Josh-Alice-Robert    2
Anna-Robert          1
Name: count, dtype: int64
"""
```