# How can I extract subchains of names from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, series

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555573/how-can-i-extract-chains-of-customers-from-a-pandas-dataframe), I have the following code capable of finding chains of customers in a database per delivery person sortie.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'DateTime': ['01/01/2023 09:00:00', '01/01/2023 09:10:00', '01/01/2023 09:15:00',
                 '01/01/2023 12:00:00', '01/01/2023 12:00:10', '01/01/2023 12:15:00',
                 '01/01/2023 15:00:00', '01/01/2023 15:05:10', '01/01/2023 15:15:00',
                 '01/01/2023 15:30:10', '01/01/2023 15:35:15', '01/01/2023 18:00:00', 
                 '01/01/2023 18:00:00', '01/01/2023 18:00:00', '01/01/2023 18:00:00'
                 , '01/01/2023 18:00:00'],
    'SortieNumber': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'CustomerName': ['Josh', 'Alice', 'Robert',
                      'Anna', 'Anna', 'Robert',
                        'Josh', 'Alice', 'Robert', 'Robert', 'Robert',
                          'Josh', 'Alice', 'Robert', 'Anna', 'Anna'],
    'ProductCode': ['001', '002', '002', '001', '003', '003', '004', '003', '001', '002', '003', '003', '003', '003', '003', '003']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
a=df.sort_values(by=['SortieNumber', 'DateTime'])
a=a.loc[lambda d: d[['SortieNumber', 'CustomerName']].ne(d[['SortieNumber', 'CustomerName']].shift()).any(axis=1)]
a=a.groupby('SortieNumber')['CustomerName'].agg('-'.join).value_counts(normalize=True)
print(a)
```

The output of this code is

```
Josh-Alice-Robert         0.50
Anna-Robert               0.25
Josh-Alice-Robert-Anna    0.25
Name: CustomerName, dtype: float64
```

Which can work with a small database, such as the one presented in the sample code above.

However, I would like to modify this code for the subchains to be considered as well, e.g., I would like

```
Josh-Alice-Robert         0.75
Josh-Alice                0.75
Alice-Robert              0.75
Anna-Robert               0.25
Robert-Anna               0.25
Josh-Alice-Robert-Anna    0.25
Name: CustomerName, dtype: float64
```

as output, since I want the chain `Josh-Alice-Robert` present `Josh-Alice-Robert-Anna` to be considered as well as a `Josh-Alice-Robert` chain.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
def my_func(g):
    d = dict.fromkeys(g["CustomerName"])
    chain = list(d)

    out = {"-".join(chain)}
    for idx in range(len(chain) - 1):
        out.add("-".join(chain[idx : idx + 2]))

    return out


df = df.sort_values(by=["SortieNumber", "DateTime"])
out = df.groupby("SortieNumber").apply(my_func).explode().value_counts(normalize=True)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
Josh-Alice                0.272727
Alice-Robert              0.272727
Josh-Alice-Robert         0.181818
Anna-Robert               0.090909
Robert-Anna               0.090909
Josh-Alice-Robert-Anna    0.090909
Name: proportion, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. I want to know the percentage of times that each series of names appears. Josh-Alice-Robert  appears in three out of four times, and Josh-Alice also appears in three out of four times, that is why the percentage is 0.75